# Magento 2 : Get option name rather option id in product collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection, attribute-options, magento2.4.0

Hi I am using below product collection,but it returns option id of attribute in collection my question is how to get option label rather than option id in collection. Is there any way ?
Because I am sending data to other endpoint

```
/**
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
private function getProductCollection()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    return $collection;
}
```

and I do not want to use below code to get option label in for loop,because I gets everytime get call in loop, Anyone has better option ?

```
$optionId = 10;

$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
 if ($attr->usesSource()) {
       $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the service contract?

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface;      
$attr = $this->productAttributeRepository->get('color')->getDefaultFrontendLabel();
```